# Having trouble converting jQuery to plain Javascript for userscripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

Okay, so here's the deal: I'm trying to create a userscript for use within Greasemonkey/Chrome/whatever else people use to manage those things. Part of what I'd like to do is to create labels for the icons I designed for this particular script. I have at least a rough idea of how to accomplish this in Jquery. The code I would have used is this:

```
$('li.tab.iconic').each(function (i) {
    var spanName = $('this').attr(id);
    var toRemove = '_button';
    var spanNameCrop = spanName.replace(toRemove,'');
    $('this').append('<span class="tooltip_label">'+spanNameCrop+'</span>');
});
```

Basically, I want to grab the `id` attribute of each `li`, trim the phrase "_button" from it, and insert the remaining text into the span that will be the label. My problem is that I've searched high and low but have found no clear instructions on how to do a loop like this in javascript. Is it even possible?

Alternatively, the website I'm styling does include the Jquery library. Is there a way to tell my script to load after the site has loaded jquery so that jquery script will work?

Edit: Got it working thanks to Avladov. Here's the final script.

```
var jQuery, $ = null;

function addJQuery(callback) {
var p = null;

if(window.opera || window.navigator.vendor.match(/Google/)) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("onclick", "return window;");
    p = div.onclick();
}
else {
    p = unsafeWindow;
}

jQuery = $ = p.jQuery.noConflict();
callback();
}

var myFunction = function() {
jQuery('#header .tab.iconic[id!="missinge_button"] a').css({"background-image":"url('http://i.imgur.com/2QmZG.png')"});

jQuery('#header .tab.iconic').each(function (i) {
    var tabID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var labelName = tabID.replace('_button','');
    if (jQuery(this).find('span[class="tooltip_label"]').length){
    }
    else{
    jQuery(this).append('<span class="tooltip_label">'+labelName+'</span>');
    jQuery('.tooltip_label').css({'text-transform':'capitalize'});
    }
});

};

addJQuery(myFunction);
```

Comment: You should not use quotes for `this` object. Use them for `id` attribute `$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: I can never remember if I need quotes or not for `this`. Fixed.

Comment: You don't need $(document).ready in a greasemonkey script. The document is already fully loaded when GM script execution begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Greasemonkey script is for a site which uses jQuery then you can use it in your script. Use this code:

```
var jQuery, $ = null;

function addJQuery(callback) {
    var p = null;

    if(window.opera || window.navigator.vendor.match(/Google/)) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("onclick", "return window;");
        p = div.onclick();
    }
    else {
        p = unsafeWindow;
    }

    jQuery = $ = p.jQuery.noConflict();
    callback();
}
```

**Callback** is a function inside your **Greasemonkey script**. After doing this you can use **jQuery** with both **jQuery** and **$** as if it's a normal web page JavaScript.

The benefit of this approach is that it will work not only for Firefox, but for Chrome and Opera too. It also doesn't load new jQuery script but reuses the one from the web page.

**Example:**

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // Your code here
};

addJQuery(myFunction);
```

**EDIT :**
There is a way to restrict the script by using **@include** and **@match** in your script Metadata Block.
You can read more about it on GM Wiki - [http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40include)

Comment: Tried this, but no joy. It also interfered with the script on other sites as well, not just on the site I'm trying to edit. Is there a way to restrict this to functioning only on the site I'm trying to edit?

Comment: I've used this in several scripts and it worked every single time. Perhaps you are doing something wrong?

Check this script I wrote. I'm using the same method. It might be of use: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/129564

Comment: Here's what I've got. I used @include to restrict its usage to tumblr and I cut out all the script to add labels so that I could test if even the most basic portion of the script-- changing the background-- was working. No dice. http://pastebin.com/nNxisHQr

Comment: I think I found at least part of the problem-- tumblr ALSO uses prototype in addition to Jquery. I'm  not sure how that affects the snippet you gave me, though.

Comment: I decided to delete everything I had and start over from the beginning, and I finally got your code working I've updated my original post with the working code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you dont want to use `'this'` you want to use `this` and if id isnt a variable string with a value you want it to be a string:

```
$('li.tab.iconic').each(function (i) {
    var spanName = $(this).attr('id');
    var toRemove = '_button';
    var spanNameCrop = spanName.replace(toRemove,'');
    $('this').append('<span class="tooltip_label">'+spanNameCrop+'</span>');
});
```

if the site isnt using jQuery you could either include jQuery for them with something like:

```
if(!(window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.jquery == '1.8.1')) {var s = document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js');s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}
```

Comment: I tried this wrapped in a document ready function, but it killed the plain javascript on my page and now neither is working. I've edited my main post to show the full script that I'm using.

Comment: if the site doesnt have jQuery then you cant use the document-ready function. Im not sure what you really want.

Comment: Greasemonkey scripts are executed on DOMContentLoaded. This is the same as document ready, so there is no need of it.

Comment: @voigtan as I said in the question and in my original post, I'm looking to convert the jquery to plain javascript. The site has jquery, but I have no idea when my script loads in relation to that, so I have no way of guaranteeing that it will insert itself/run after jquery's inclusion in the head.

Answer (score 0):

Add your jquery script inside of a document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li.tab.iconic').each(function (i) {
    var spanName = $('this').attr('id');
    var toRemove = '_button';
    var spanNameCrop = name.replace(toRemove,'');
    $(this).append('<span class="tooltip_label">'+spanNameCrop+'</span>');
});
})
```

The code will now execute when all resources on the page have been grabbed

You can read more here:
http://api.jquery.com/ready/